# Suppose f, g : [a, b] → R are bounded, and P is a partition of [a, b]. Show that L(f + g, P) ≥ L(f, P) + L(g, P) and U(f + g, P) ≤ U(f, P) + U(g, P)

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose f, g : [a, b] → R are bounded, and P is a partition of [a, b]. Show that L(f + g, P) ≥ L(f, P) + L(g, P) and U(f + g, P) ≤ U(f, P) + U(g, P)

I don't quite know where to start, and I don't understand what the point of the question is, and I can only find references online to Rudin's textbook but I do not have that textbook and so I am at a loss. Any help or hints greatly appreciated!

Comment: At least you know what the definitions of the various terms such as $L(f,P)$ and $U(f,P)$ are, right? For context , please tell us where you got this problem from.

Answer (score 0):

The proof follows from the fact that supremum is sub-additive and infimum is super-additive. 
Regarding the motivation of this problem, one immediate consequence is that if $ f $ and $ g $ are Riemann integrable, then $ f+g $ is Riemann integrable, and this result follows directly from the definition of Riemann integrability.